# How to prevent ioloop.PeriodicCallback run in every process in tornado tcpserver multiprocessing mode?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, tornado

I start up a tornado tcpserver like this:

```
def main():
    server = Server()
    server.bind(8989)
    server.start(9)  # **Forks multiple sub-processes**
    io_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
    check_time = 1 * 1000  # every second
    scheduler = ioloop.PeriodicCallback(app.periodic_job,
                                    check_time,
                                    io_loop=io_loop)
    scheduler.start()
    io_loop.start()
```

I Forks 9 sub-processes,and create a scheduler,I hope the scheduler only run once but not run in every process.how can I do?

Comment: Have you tested this? It should work exactly as you've written it. Everything after `start(N)` is run in every process.

Comment: I have run it , the problem is : app.periodic_job run 9 times every second,and i hope it run only one time every second

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread the question. I'll answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use the ["advanced multi-process"](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpserver.html) mode instead of `HTTPServer.start()`. `fork_processes()` returns a task ID, so you can run the `PeriodicCallback` only in a certain task.

```
def main():
    sockets = tornado.netutil.bind_sockets(8989)
    task_id = tornado.process.fork_processes(9)
    server = Server()
    server.add_sockets(sockets)
    io_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
    if task_id == 0:
        check_time = 1 * 1000  # every second
        scheduler = ioloop.PeriodicCallback(app.periodic_job,
                                check_time,
                                io_loop=io_loop)
        scheduler.start()
    io_loop.start()
```

Comment: You can get `task_id`, started with HTTPServer/TCPServer.start(N) as well, from `tornado.process.task_id()`

Comment: It work greate,Thanks for your help! and the feathur of task_id can help me to seperate diffrent job in diffrent process.Greate!